# calculating the Jacobian in polar coordinates geometrically

Tags: polar-coordinates, jacobian

The task sounds like this: “geometrically calculate the Jacobian of polar substitution.” In this case, we get the expression dxdy=rdrd(theta)+ 4s, where 4s are the remaining pieces when inserted. But at the same time, this is wrong or not entirely correct, I was told that I need to solve this somehow differently, and at the same time it can be solved very simply, as I was told.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUjTs.png)

Comment: What is $s$ ? There is no need for an internal "right side up" square. You can approximate the curved cake shape as being a square with side lengths $dr$ and $rd\theta$

Comment: What is the point, that the Jacobian of polar substitution needs to be calculated geometrically, while approximating some areas to 0 to fulfill the equality is not correct. And I don’t know how to prove that the Jacobian in the polar coordinate system is equal to r using only drawings and data from drawings.

Comment: this is not it, you need to describe geometrically why the Jacobian in polar coordinates is equal to r.

Comment: You're telling me "this is not it" when I have taught this subject for 10 years and know exactly what the question asking for, as well as the other posters to your question. I am giving you the correct clues to get the answer as intended. If you choose not to listen, no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation of the volume element in $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ is the alternating wedge product

$$\begin{align}\mathrm dx \wedge \mathrm dy &= \mathrm d(r \cos \theta )\wedge \mathrm d(r \sin \theta) \\&=(\mathrm dr \cos \theta- \mathrm d\theta\,r \sin \theta) \wedge (\mathrm d r \sin \theta + \mathrm d\theta\,r \cos \theta)\\& = r\,\mathrm dr\wedge \mathrm d\theta\,(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta) \\& = \mathrm dr \wedge r\,\mathrm d\theta \end{align}$$

The last expression is simply the rectangular area between to circles with radial distance $\mathrm dr$ and two radial rays with arc length $r\,\mathrm d\theta$ between them.

In orthogonal coordinates the volume element is always the product of the coordinate differentials multiplied by their scale factors

Comment: but this is not a geometric proof, you just did the math, but you need to deduce r based on the picture

Comment: Even if its not common knowledge, exterior calculus is purely geometrical based on what directions of 1-d edges are assumed to be linear independent, times sign of permutions of directions in any dimension. Grassmanns idea seemed so strange to euclidean geometers, that only in the late 1950 his ideas became slowly stuff of lessons in analysis, that clinged to euclidean geometry, that has nothing do do with multidimensional integration algorithms by coordinate transform.